# Android - What is the relation between processes and notifications?

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to understand the relation between notifications and processes in android:

1. An android process with active notification, but no open activity, is considered ["cached" or "visible"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html)? I.e. would android try to kill that process on inactivity or spare it due to active notification?
2. If the process IS killed by android, would the notification be cleared too? I assume it is, because when I kill a process through Android's application manager, its notifications disappear as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found out based on logs:

1. Notification does not save a process from being killed. If Android is low on memory, the process will be cleared regardless of its current notifications.
2. Notification of a cleared process aren't removed when Android kills the process due to memory concerns. It only clears the notifications if you manually do "Kill process" from Android's process management control panel.